# ifstream read method is synchronous?

Tags: c++

I'm making a Snake game using ANSI escape codes in C++. I want to get the keyboard input and, for example, when I press <kbd>W</kbd> then the snake will move up and the direction will be set to `U` so it will keep moving up until I press another direction key:

```cpp
void Map::getSnakeMovement(char *path) {                                                                                                     ifstream keyboardFile(path, ios::in | ios::binary);                                                                          
        keyboardInput kbInput;                                                                                                       
                                                                                                                                     
        if (!keyboardFile) {
                cerr << "Cannot read the keyboard input" << endl;
                return;
        }

        while(1) {
                keyboardFile.read((char*)&kbInput, sizeof(keyboardInput));

                switch(this->currentDirection) {
                        case 'L':
                                this->snake[0].move(this->snake[0].getXPosition() - 1, this->snake[0].getYPosition());
                                this->isPoint(this->snake[0].getXPosition(), this->snake[0].getYPosition());
                                this->scoreboard.display();
                                break;

                        case 'U':
                                this->snake[0].move(this->snake[0].getXPosition(), this->snake[0].getYPosition() - 1);
                                this->isPoint(this->snake[0].getXPosition(), this->snake[0].getYPosition());
                                this->scoreboard.display();
                                break;
                        case 'R':
                                this->snake[0].move(this->snake[0].getXPosition() + 1, this->snake[0].getYPosition());
                                this->isPoint(this->snake[0].getXPosition(), this->snake[0].getYPosition());
                                this->scoreboard.display();
                                break;

                        case 'D':
                                this->snake[0].move(this->snake[0].getXPosition(), this->snake[0].getYPosition() + 1);
                                this->isPoint(this->snake[0].getXPosition(), this->snake[0].getYPosition());
                                this->scoreboard.display();
                                break;
                }

                if (kbInput.type == 1 && kbInput.value == 1 && kbInput.code != 0) {
                        switch(kbInput.code) {
                                case W_KEY:
                                        this->currentDirection = 'U';
                                        break;
                                case A_KEY:
                                        this->currentDirection = 'L';
                                        break;
                                case S_KEY:
                                        this->currentDirection = 'D';
                                        break;
                                case D_KEY:
                                        this->currentDirection = 'R';
                                        break;
                        }
                }
                Utils::moveCursor(this->height + 20, 1);
        }

        keyboardFile.close();
}
```

But the result is not as expected. Is the read method blocking the flow?

Comment: C++ streams are (effectively) fully synchronous. There's no way to do keyboard inputs here like you want with C++ streams. You need some other C++ library, usually OS specific.

Comment: or use threads no? But i'm currently reading a book and i haven't covered threads yet. thank you for your response .

Comment: I guess if you had a thread consuming input faster than the keyboard could produce it, then you could kinda sorta fake it yes.  You'd only get to text inputs though. No ctrl, shift, arrows, numpad, etc.

Comment: why? ctrl shift etc don't work the same way? producing codes like all the other keys?

Comment: Keyboards produce key_up and key_down events, which the OS receives.  The OS passes these to the terminal program, which it analyzes the ctrl+shift+letter events and interprets them as text.  The terminal then streams this _text_ via `std::cin` to the program that the terminal is running.  This is also why you can't backspace/delete with a stream. It's a stream of text, not raw keyboard input. Note that it's identical to streaming text from a file.